# как объединить выборки двух filter в django?

Tags: python, django

**views**

```
    search_query = 'sometext'
    search_filter_one = Orders.objects.filter(Q(device__icontains=search_query))
    # ... some code ...
    search_query = 'anothertext'
    search_filter_two = Orders.objects.filter(Q(device__icontains=search_query))
    results_query = results + search_filter # <-- схематичный смысл желаемого
```

как объединить выборки двух `filter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
search_filter_three = Orders.objects.filter(
    Q(device__icontains=search_query_1) | Q(device__icontains=search_query_2)

)
```

или для удобства

```py
conds = Q(device__icontains=search_query_1) | Q(device__icontains=search_query_2)

search_filter_three = Orders.objects.filter(conds)
```

[Дока](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Добавить |

```
Q(device__icontains=search_query_1) | Q(device__icontains=search_query_2)
```